# C# / Silverlight: SL classlibrary referenced in "normal" C# - application, must Silverlight be installed?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, reference

So, I want to share TONS of code between Silverlight and "normal" applications. Starting with utility functions and all that up to my hand coded framework (MVC, DI, etc...)...

Here is my question:

Imagine I have put all this stuff into a SL - Classlibrary, lets call it "AmazingLibrary" and I reference it in a NORMAL (say, WPF) project that doesn't use Silverlight...

Will I have to make the people enjoying my WPF - application install Silverlight first or is the assembly just "a little bit different, but still runs under normal CLR 3.5"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't need to have people install SilverLight to use your external library.  The SilverLight class library can just reference a subset of what is in .net.

Here is a link describing the differences between a normal library and a SilverLight library:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/17088869/SilverLight-Class-Library-vs-Normal-Class-Library

Comment: Now THATS amazing, if that really works, wow!! :-) Thank you very much for your fast answer!